# Instrumental: lead guitar, orchestral accompaniment

Tags: identify-this-song, instrumental

I have this beautiful instrumental music on my computer, but it has no information attached:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1iqp0kGPjWsb3B2RkUzeTNPcE0/view

Comment: This sounds like ["Muzak"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muzak) an influential background music library that at one time produced many similar recordings, typically orchestrating a popular song, and replacing the vocal line with an acoustic guitar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La Reine De Saba by Claude Ciari.

[You can listen to a sample here.](http://www.allmusic.com/album/claude-ciari-mw0001327177)